Is it possible to get audio stream events notification in a Win32 app?
Windows supports the audio session events notification by IAudioSessionEvents. I want to know that is it possible to get audio stream events notification, such as an application creates an audio stream and add it to a session? Because I want to know that how many audio streams are in an audio session.
I can receive the notification when an applicaiton creates an audio session by IAudioSessionEvents, but I can not receive a notification when an application add a stream to the existing audio session.
